AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'compiled' while using gridsearch.fit
All the 2880 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.
Below are more details about the failures:
2880 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/devendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 888, in _fit_and_score
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
File "/home/devendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py", line 1501, in fit
super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs)
File "/home/devendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py", line 770, in fit
self._fit(
File "/home/devendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py", line 928, in _fit
self._ensure_compiled_model()
File "/home/devendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py", line 439, in ensure_compiled_model
if not self.model.compiled:
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'compiled'
def create_model(neurons_1,neurons_2,optimizer,learning_rate,dropout):
    
    cnn = models.Sequential([
        layers.Conv1D(filters=neurons_1, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', input_shape=(82,1)),
        layers.MaxPooling1D(4),
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        
        layers.Conv1D(filters=neurons_2, kernel_size=8, activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling1D(4),
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dropout(dropout),
        layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dropout(dropout),
        
        layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
    ])
            
    
    cnn.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss= tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    
    return cnn


model = KerasClassifier(model=create_model)

params={
    'epochs':[20,50,100],
    'model__neurons_1':[16,32,64,128],
    'model__neurons_2':[16,32,64,128],
    'model__optimizer':['adam','SGD'],
    'model__dropout':[0.2,0.5],
    'model__learning_rate':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1]
    
    }

# labels
y_val = train_df.TB_status.values
# data
X_val = train_df[feat_names]

grid= GridSearchCV(estimator=model,param_grid=params,cv=5,verbose=1)

transformer = RobustScaler().fit(X_val)
X_r_scaled = transformer.transform(X_val)
grid_search = grid.fit(X_r_scaled, y_val)


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

To fine-tune hyperparameters using GridSearchCV, begin by installing the
scikeras library. Preprocess your data and define your model. Next, define a
dictionary containing hyperparameter names and their potential values. Wrap
your model within the KerasClassifier class. Finally, pass the wrapped model
and the hyperparameter dictionary to GridSearchCV and initiate the training
process with the fit method. I have implemented GridSearchCv , refer to the
provided gist.
